# Deduct amount from total during onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a promotion and I need the end user to see that if a user is in a specific state, with a specific property type and a specific plan.. they will get $50 off the total amount.

Here is something along the lines of what I have.

```
var CurrentDate = new Date();
var SelectedDate = new Date(2014, 8, 1);
if(CurrentDate < SelectedDate){
    var promoState = $("#PropertyState").val();
    var propertyType = $("#PropertyType").val();
    if (promoState == "FL"){
        if (propertyType == "6"){
            var creditFL = $(" /*$50 off total*/");
            var total = $("#SpantotalPremium");
            creditFL.trigger("click");
        }
    }  
}
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here. The application that I'm using defaults to the plan which is #BasePlan1 (the plan with the discount) so I'm not sure the on click is necessary unless they look at something else first and then click back to that plan.

Does this make sense? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if that part is validation you probably would want to validate it server side instead, client side should make checks just for display

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where it is you're stuck. The code appears to make sense (at least in a general sense from your requirement description). Can you elaborate on what you're uncertain about?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much of your application but from what have described, these rules should be in the server side since they are sensitive information and being in the client side the user could hack their usage.

Moreover, it is much simpler to create the UI based on these rules in the server side than in the client side.

**UPDATE:**

If this must done in the client side. I believe you should take the following approach:

1. Put the amount of discount in ha hidden field, because it can later be send to the server side so the discount is taken into account
2. Add a message in the UI stating the user has the discount.
3. If you need to call a javascript event triggered by a button, call the javascript function directly instead of clicking programatically, simply because it is simpler.

Comment: I 100% agree and it's what I mentioned. Unfortunately, where I'm at now doesn't agree with that. For now, they want it hard-coded into the page..

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check whether it helps.

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to say that this type of functionality could be dangerous to the business. Applying a discount based on a javascript click event isn't really a good way to handle the process. User's can easily intercept this value and give them whatever discount they want. If it must be done client side, maybe an ajax call to a server side file would be better. Then you process your back-end logic to handle if the user had already received a discount. Also this way can force validation.

Comment: I agree and @Christina is quite aware of that.

Comment: Just for understanding, what is the purpose that this must be added statically to the page. I am just trying to get a scope of context to provide you a better solution.

Comment: Right now, where I'm at it has to be (I just started here), and things are slowly changing. I told them this is shouldn't be done this way, but I can't argue non-top with the CTO, I can only tell him my opinion. @eg_dac

Comment: @Christina, please code a little bit more, following my suggestions, if you will, and update the questions if you have more problems. If you need more guidance regarding my answer, let me know.